# Assigning names(or alias) to projectname.databasename.column name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know this might be very elementary, it's my first time posting, but I'm stuck trying to do a small portfolio project in BigQuery.

I am trying to INNER JOIN 2 tables so that i can set reviews.listing_id = listings.id
(listing_id in the reviews table = id from the listings table)

the hard part or the sloppy part comes from the syntax as I keep getting string errors and unexpected input errors:

is it:

`mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings.id` = `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB.reviews.listing_id` ??

or:

is there a way I can alias `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings` AS `listings` and `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.reviews` AS `reviews` so the table name can just be listings.id = reviews.listings_id?

this is the full code im trying to run:

SELECT host_id, host_url, host_name, COUNT(*) AS num_dirty_reviews FROM reviews
INNER JOIN `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings` ON `mark-data- analytics.AirBnB_data.reviews.listing_id` = `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings.id`
WHERE comments LIKE "%dirty%"
GROUP BY host_id, host_url, host_name
ORDER BY num_dirty_reviews DESC;

edit: Thanks Thom A this code worked for me:

SELECT listings.host_id, listings.host_url, listings.host_name, COUNT(*) AS num_dirty_reviews
FROM `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.reviews`AS reviews, `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings`AS listings
INNER JOIN `mark-data-analytics.AirBnB_data.listings` ON reviews.listing_id = listings.id
WHERE comments LIKE "%dirty%"
GROUP BY host_id, host_url, host_name ORDER BY num_dirty_reviews DESC;

Comment: [SQL Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: Well now that you've removed the [[tag:sql-server]] I can't help you; I was here due to the incorrect tags.